# ESP32 Upload user files then encrypt flash

Tags: esp32, micropython, esp-idf

I am using an esp32-s3-DevKitC-1. I am flashing micropython v1.21.0 with esp-idf-v5.0.4.

How can I upload user files using something like ampy before encryption?

I've tried three methods so far:

Method One
`idf.py menuconfig` (setup without flash encryption enabled)
`idf.py flash`
Use ampy to push files
`idf.py menuconfig` (setup with flash encryption enabled)
`idf.py flash`

Method Two
`idf.py menuconfig` (setup without flash encryption enabled)
`idf.py flash`
Use ampy to push files
`espefuse.py burn_efuse SPI_BOOT_CRYPT_CNT`

Method Three
`idf.py menuconfig` (setup with flash encryption enabled)
`idf.py flash`
Use ampy to push files (Nothing happens)
then reset

Specifically, in the documentation - [Using Host Generated Key Step 5](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/release-v5.0/esp32s3/security/flash-encryption.html#disabling-flash-encryption) - it states after running `idf.py flash monitor`

"This command does not include any user files which should be written to the partitions on the flash memory. Please write them manually before running this command otherwise the files should be encrypted separately before writing."

but does not provide any further explanation as to how this is done.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you're trying to do and what the expected outcome is.